# how to exclude the most recent null field from query result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to design a query to find out is there at least one cat (select count(*) where rownum = 1) that haven't been checked out.

One weird condition is that the result should exclude if the most recent cat that didn't checked out, so that:

```
TABLE schedule
-------------------------------------
|  type | checkin  |  checkout
-------------------------------------
|  cat  |  20:10  |   (null)
|  dog  |  19:35  |   (null)
|  dog  |  19:35  |   (null)
|  cat  |  15:31  |   (null)   ----> exclude this cat in this scenario
|  dog  |  12:47  |   13:17
|  dog  |  10:12  |   12:45
|  cat  |  08:27  |   11:36
```

should return 1, the first record

```
|  cat  |  20:10  |   (null)
```

I kind of create the query like

```
select * from schedule where type = 'cat' and checkout is null order by checkin desc
```

however this query does not resolve the exclusion. I can sure handle it in the service layer like java, but just wondering any solution can design in the query and with **good performance** when there is **large amount of data** in the table ( checkin and checkout are indexed but not type)

Comment: What data type are `checkin` and `checkout`? It looks like string (perhaps `varchar2`) which will cause very poor execution efficiency. If that is indeed so and you require good performance, you should change it to the proper data type (DATE). Then, what should happen if two cats who were not checked out are tied for "most recent `checkin`"?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Select *
From schedule
Where type='cat' and checkin=(select max(checkin) from schedule where type='cat' and checkout is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `checkin` and `checkout` data type is string (which it shouldn't be, it should be DATE), `to_char(checkin, 'hh24:mi')` will create a value of the proper data type, DATE, assuming the first day of the current month as the "date" portion. It shouldn't matter to you, since presumably all the hours are from the same date. If in fact `checkin/out` are in the proper DATE data type, you don't need the `to_date()` call in `order by` (in two places).

I left out the `checkout` column from the output, since you are only looking for the rows with `null` in that column, so including it would provide no information. I would have left out `type` as well, but perhaps you'll want to have this for cats AND dogs at some later time...

```
with
     schedule( type, checkin, checkout ) as (
       select 'cat', '20:10', null    from dual union all
       select 'dog', '19:35', null    from dual union all
       select 'dog', '19:35', null    from dual union all
       select 'cat', '15:31', null    from dual union all
       select 'dog', '12:47', '13:17' from dual union all
       select 'dog', '10:12', '12:45' from dual union all
       select 'cat', '08:27', '11:36' from dual
     )
-- end of test data; actual solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select type, checkin
from   ( select type, checkin, 
                row_number() over (order by to_date(checkin, 'hh24:mi')) as rn
         from   schedule
         where  type = 'cat' and checkout is null
       )
where  rn > 1
order by to_date(checkin, 'hh24:mi')   --  ORDER BY is optional
;

TYPE  CHECKIN
----  -------
cat   20:10
```